# Encoding in node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I've just started using node.js and node-mysql, and I faced the following trouble:
I send data from client (Angular.js). The server (node.js) is sending it to mysql database.
Server.js (part):

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
mysql = require('node-mysql2');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(someSettings);
...skipped part...
app.put('/api/announcements', function(req, res) {
    connection.execute('INSERT INTO announcements(title, text) VALUES(?, ?)', [req.body.title, req.body.text]);
    res.send({status: true});
});
```

the thing is, if I send latin letters in request fields `title` and `text`, that's ok. But if I try to send cyrillic ones, appears the following issue:

```
app.put('/api/announcements', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.title, req.body.text); // <- shows the whole strings
    ...
```

but in the table there is only part of the string! (I mean, fields `title` and `text` of the new record consist only part of the string.

Screenshots to explain:
[image: first query (console.log result)]
[image: second query]
[image: phpMyAdmin]

UPD:
here's an example so you could try it yourself. The archive consists of table export file (announcements.sql) and www folder for cordova project. You will also need plugins: express, mysql2, promise, nodejs-websocket. The idea is that I start 2 servers: on 88 port to handle REST requests and on 89 to broadcast changes to all connected clients. Try the following test: open an index page in browser and try to add these strings: 1. There is a place where the sidewalk ends 2. Есть место, где заканчивается тротуар; sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96085/1 db.tt/GfvjmXtU

Comment: Your post isn't quite clear enough to figure out what you mean; is there an error? I don't know russian, is that russian wrong? On a secondary note, something that's certainly worth doing is to stop using a mysq-specific library and use something like the "sequelize" library instead, so that you aren't issuing "sql queries" but simply ask for model-adhering records to be written and read.

Comment: Yes, there is an error, because only half of the string is being written to database. As for sequelize, thanks for the advice, I'll try it. But one thing bothers me: I may be wrong, but isn't it using node-mysql module? If so, there may be the same issue

Comment: the difference is in the way you call sequelize; you don't tell it to execute SQL statements, you simply manipulate records in an object, and sequelize takes care of making sure your SQL backend is updated accordingly. With regards to the error: can you show what you expect to see, what you see instead, and what the data in your SQL table looks like?

Comment: sure, I provided screenshots from command line and phpMyAdmin. I expect to see the following string in my table: 'Погруженный в скорбь немую', instead I see: 'Погруженный в' (i.e. only 13 symbols out of 26, exactly half)

Comment: yes, but those screenshots are not enough (and should be in text form, quoted as code, not images). We need to see what data is in your table (missing), the query you run on it (you already show that), and the specific result (might be the screenshot or might not). You may also want to include a link to a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example, to show what it really should be doing

Comment: Sorry for the long silence, here's an example so you could try it yourself. The archive consists of table export file (announcements.sql) and www folder for cordova project. You will also need plugins: express, mysql2, promise, nodejs-websocket. The idea is that I start 2 servers: on 88 port to handle REST requests and on 89 to broadcast changes to all connected clients. Try the following test: open an index page in browser and try to add these strings: 
1. There is a place where the sidewalk ends
2. Есть место, где заканчивается тротуар; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96085/1 https://db.tt/GfvjmXtU

Comment: please edit your post instead of adding all that information in a comment. It's not just for me, it's for everyone who finds your question and might be able to answer it.

Comment: Could you check if this still happen? Sounds like incorrect use of `str.length` vs `Buffer.byteLength(str, 'utf8');` - might be already fixed (and if not - please fill as github issue)

Comment: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/commit/cf9594aaab5b3d51a112bd1f43b39a55f508eef7

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this error appears only if I use `connection.execute()`. `connection.query()` works fine. I didn't yet dig out the reasons of such behaviour, but the difference is:

If I use

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO announcements VALUES("Расти борода, расти")');
```

Query.toPacket (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/query.js) returns

```
{
    sequenceId: 0,
    buffer: <Buffer 04 00 00 00 03 49 ...>,
    offset: 83,
    start: 0,
    end: 83
}
```

And

```
connection.execute('INSERT INTO announcements VALUES("Расти борода, расти")');
```

Execute.toPacket (/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/execute.js) returns

```
{
    sequenceId: 0,
    buffer: <Buffer 88 07 5d 01 17 02 ...>,
    offset: 38,
    start: 0,
    end: 54
}
```